# grep to match filename in full path

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I want to "extract" the file name in a full path string using grep.

For example:

- In /etc/network/interfaces I want to match "interfaces".
- In /home/user/Documents/report.pdf I want to match "report.pdf".

Basically I want the opposite of:

```
$ ls /etc/network/interfaces | grep "^.*/"
```

I tried:

```
$ ls -p /etc/network/interfaces | grep "/.*$"
```

But it won't be the last slash (/), all chars (.*), until the end ($). Since slashes are chars as well, it matches all the path.

Does anyone know a way to match only the last part? Something like (from last slash until the end.

Thank you,

Comment: you can use `basename` command to get the file name out of the path. Eg: `basename /var/log/messages` will return me `messages`.

Comment: I didn't know basename @PS. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk`, getting the `/` separated last field:

```
% awk -F/ '{print $NF}' <<<'/etc/network/interfaces'
interfaces

% awk -F/ '{print $NF}' <<<'/home/user/Documents/report.pdf'
report.pdf
```

---

`grep`, getting the portion after last `/`:

```
% grep -o '[^/]\+$' <<<'/etc/network/interfaces'
interfaces

% grep -o '[^/]\+$' <<<'/home/user/Documents/report.pdf'
report.pdf
```

---

`sed`, replacing everything upto the last `/` with null:

```
% sed 's_.*/__' <<<'/etc/network/interfaces' 
interfaces

% sed 's_.*/__' <<<'/home/user/Documents/report.pdf'
report.pdf
```

Comment: nice, so many options. Thank you a lot. In the grep part, I kinda dont understand what \+ does there.

Answer (score 2):

How about simply matching on not `/`? Also, for extraction, you need the `-o` flag to `grep`.

```
ls -p /etc/network/interfaces | grep -o '[^/]*$'
```

Comment: this is perfect, I totally got confused on the [^/] part but your answer cleared up. Thanks

Comment: `-P` is not needed and good practice to use single quotes unless double are needed to avoid shell interpretation... `grep -o '[^/]*$'` ... and there is already a command for this.. `basename '/etc/network/interfaces'`

Comment: @Sundeep, Thanks for corrections. I usually default to using `-P` so that I only need to remember one dialect of regex instead of n. :P

Answer (score 0):

As said in the first comment you can directly try using awk something like:

```
ls -l /etc/networks | awk '{print $NF}' | awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'
```

It should be possible to trim these 2 awk pipes as well